# Apply a function on all Select statements on table implicitly - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to apply some function (user defined / system) to selected columns automatically, may be binding it at schema level.

My scenario is I am saving timestamps of record saving in each table automatically, for which I have used `getdate()`  as default value of those columns, It was working fine till we had our own hosting. But since now we are moving to shared hosting and don't know in which timezone the servers shall be placed in future, I am using `GETUTCDATE()` to get GMT time.

Since a lot of procedures / functions are already in place, I am looking for something where I don't need to convert this UTC time to my local time explicitly.

So that my `Select * from MyTable` shall give me time in my fixed timezone using the function I've created.

Let me know if its possible by any way.

Thanks.

Comment: No answers.. Does it mean its simply not possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you want to do, but there's no way to replace what the `SELECT` statement asks for with something else: what you ask for in a query is what you get. Unless you replace a table with a view with the same name, but that probably isn't the best approach.

Using a view or function would still mean you have to change your code anyway, so why not  just `UPDATE` all data to UTC time and then do the conversion in your application code? SQL Server has no idea what time zone a client is in anyway, so it isn't possible to do the conversion reliably on the server side. Unless perhaps the client sends the local time zone to the server as a parameter or in [`CONTEXT_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but there wouldn't be much point because doing it in the client would be simpler anyway.

And of course handling it all in the application will give you a much more flexible, robust solution.

Comment: Even I think what I was expecting is more than SQL provides as of now. I need to modify all my procedures and functions now. Thanks though.